# countUp.js doesnt load

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

I have tried to set up countUp.js but it fails to load, I'm pretty new to Javascript or Jquery so maybe I did something wrong?

```
<div id="count"></div>
```

// Could there be a problem with the script?

```
var options = {  
  useEasing: true,
    useGrouping: true,
    separator: ',',
    decimal: '.'  
  prefix: ''  
  suffix: ''
}
var test = new countUp("count", 1350, 10000, 0, 5000, options);
demo.start();
```

**[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/b30z4w8w/)**

Comment: As a good advice, use your console to debug

Comment: And to add to what @A.Wolff said: you can use `console.log()` and `console.debug()` to print strings and variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First some properties of your object are missing their trailing `,`, so you have syntax errors. Also, you need to call `start()` on the `test` variable, not `demo`. Try this:

```
var options = {  
    useEasing: true,
    useGrouping: true,
    separator: ',',
    decimal: '.',
    prefix: '',  
    suffix: ''
}
var test = new countUp("count", 1350, 10000, 0, 5000, options);
test.start();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b30z4w8w/2/)

Comment: Thanks, this worked on the jsfiddle file but not on my website, I'm still getting errors on chrome console http://i.imgur.com/5wra4t2.png

Comment: Without seeing your code that's going to be tricky to diagnose.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Saed6o3.png the problem seems to be on the countup.js file

Comment: and heres my code http://i.imgur.com/AEjY1Sh.png

Comment: You're including jQuery twice there, remove one of those.

Comment: Ok so I removed the .min one but it still doesn't load

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question for that - including your full HTML and JS code if you can.

Comment: Here's the code http://jsfiddle.net/pd8z71o5/

It doesnt work on the jsfiddle either

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket: http://jsfiddle.net/pd8z71o5/2/ First thing to check if something isn't working: the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68822/discussion-between-common-and-rory-mccrossan).